# Angular 2 - Call method of a different (service-)component

Tags: angular

I have a dashboard-component that displays a list of documents.
For each document in the list i would like to provide a "delete-link".

Is there a way to **directly call the delete-method of my document-service** out of the dashboards html-template, rather than calling a method of my dashboard-component which forwards to the document-service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
(click)="documentService.someMethod($event)"
```

Comment: OK... It really was that simple! Thank you!